# Replace single digit with 'space and digit' Python ex: ASSESSMENT _2/28

Tags: python, regex, format

```
DF_Column:         ASSESSMENT
            ASSESSMENT 21/28, MISSED
            ASSESSMENT 1/28, MISSED
            ASSESSMENT 2/28, MISSED
            ASSESSMENT 23/28, MISSED
            ASSESSMENT 23/28, MISSED
            ASSESSMENT 5/28, MISSED
```

What I want in python:

```
               ASSESSMENT
        ASSESSMENT 21/28, MISSED
        ASSESSMENT  1/28, MISSED
        ASSESSMENT  2/28, MISSED
        ASSESSMENT 23/28, MISSED
        ASSESSMENT 23/28, MISSED
        ASSESSMENT  5/28, MISSED
```

There should be double space after ASSESSMENT if it is singleDigit/28

Comment: Use number formatting with field width = 2 and right justification.

Comment: But how should that be done only to the rows with singledigit/28 and avoid the once doubleDigit/28?

Comment: Why do you only need to do it to rows with singledigit? If it has 2 digits, putting it in a width-2 field will just fill the field with the digits, and not add any spaces.

Comment: @Barmar that would be fine if Chethana was the one that made the table, but if they are formatting the table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Python [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to find the date pattern and replace with a new string, and Python [rjust](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust) to realign the date in a string of length 2.

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', sep='\n')
print(df)

def fix_alignment(m):
    g1 = m.group(1).rjust(2, ' ')
    g2 = m.group(2)
    return f'{g1}/{g2}'

df['NewAlignment'] = df['ASSESSMENT'].apply(
        lambda row: re.sub(r'\b(\d{1})/(\d{2})', fix_alignment, row)
)
print(df)
```

Output from *df*

```py
                 ASSESSMENT              NewAlignment
0  ASSESSMENT 21/28, MISSED  ASSESSMENT 21/28, MISSED
1   ASSESSMENT 1/28, MISSED  ASSESSMENT  1/28, MISSED
2   ASSESSMENT 2/28, MISSED  ASSESSMENT  2/28, MISSED
3  ASSESSMENT 23/28, MISSED  ASSESSMENT 23/28, MISSED
4  ASSESSMENT 23/28, MISSED  ASSESSMENT 23/28, MISSED
5   ASSESSMENT 5/28, MISSED  ASSESSMENT  5/28, MISSED
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses the two spaces in the field as a split character. Then it makes sure the middle substring is 6 characters long (including whitespace). I tested this on an array that was made from your column.

```
['{} {:>6} {}'.format(*i.split(' ')) for i in col]
```

And here is code I just used on a dataframe

```
df['ASSESSMENT'] = ['{} {:>6} {}'.format(*i.split(' ')) for i in df['ASSESSMENT']]
```